# Flutter: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

Flutter -
Im trying to run firebase auth for user authentication for my flutter app but I've been met with so many errors. Currently, Im having trouble with 'fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found
#import <GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h>'

can you help me out? What am I missing?

below is my podfile.lock

```
PODS:
  - Firebase/Analytics (3.6.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.4.2)
  - Firebase/Auth (7.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 7.3.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (7.3.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 7.3.0)
  - firebase_auth (0.20.0-1):
    - Firebase/Auth (= 7.3.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core (0.7.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.3.0)
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseAnalytics (3.4.2):
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
    - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.2)
  - FirebaseAuth (7.3.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.4)
  - FirebaseCore (7.3.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.0)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (7.6.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.0)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (8.2.0):
    - nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)
  - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.2.2):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.2.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.5.0)
  - nanopb (2.30907.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 2.30907.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 2.30907.0)
  - nanopb/decode (2.30907.0)
  - nanopb/encode (2.30907.0)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.12)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Firebase/Analytics
  - firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)
  - firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)


PODFILE CHECKSUM: bc1d24e77f14f92074f70a556e48b173f43f1d27

COCOAPODS: 1.10.1
```

Comment: I had a similar error "Modules Issue (Xcode): Definition of 'GULAppEnvironmentUtil' must be imported from module 'GoogleUtilities.GULAppEnvironmentUtil' before it is          
required ", while running `flutter build ios --release` . I didn't find a fix for this, but was able to successfully build from XCode for Simulator and Archive. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Look patiently through your `Podfile.lock` file and check the installed versions of your `Google*` and `Firebase*` pods. In my case there were *FirebaseAnalytics* with version 3.6.2 when all other Firebase pods has major version of 8. Then look through the dependencies (who uses this pod with small version) and try to find which pod bring you wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you added google service plist
And try  with terminal

pod deintegrate

Pod setup

Pod install

Flutter run
If not

then

Close xcode

First add to

Pod file

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'Firebase/Core'

pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

pod 'Firebase/Storage'

pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

Then go to terminal

pod deintegrate

Pod setup

Pod install

Flutter run

Then should work fine

Use xcode after that

Answer (score 0):

In your Podfile move ALL your Firebase related pod declarations to right below the line with `target 'Runner' do`.
Move means delete them from wherever they are now and place them exactly as described here.

After that, the target will look somewhat like this:

target 'Runner' do
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.69.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(**FILE**))
end

After that run:

cd ios (from your project root directory)

flutter clean
rm -fr Pods Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
flutter pub get
pod update

and try to build your app again

You may also need to add firebase_analytics package to your pubspec.yaml even if you do not explicitly use it in your code (there may be some workaround that eliminates the need to do so, but I am not aware of how to do that).

Here's an excerpt from my pubspec with Firebase related entries

firebase_core: ^1.0.3
firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1

Strangely enough the iOS compilation will fail with the following:
`fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h' file not found #import <GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h>` if I remove the firebase_analytic package

Comment: I am facing 'GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h' file not found #import  error. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: did u find the solution for this?